# Do when any of N events happens, but using the last result of all other events

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

Let's say that there are N events. Can I do something when an event E happens, where E is an event in the N events, but only after each of the events has happened at least once, and use the last result for each event?

I have tried the code below, expecting the result would be like that in the comments

```
val o1 = PublishSubject.create<String>();
val o2 = PublishSubject.create<String>();
val o3 = PublishSubject.create<String>();

Observable.zip(o1,o2,o3,
        Function3<String, String, String, Array<String>> { t1, t2, t3 -> arrayOf(t1,t2,t3); })
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe { t1 ->
            Log.d("so", "Result = " + t1.joinToString(" "));
        }

o1?.onNext("homer"); //o2 and o3 have not been ready.
Thread.sleep(1000);
o1?.onNext("bart");  //o2 and o3 have not been ready.
Thread.sleep(1000);
o3?.onNext("doughnut"); //o2 has not been ready.
Thread.sleep(1000);
o2?.onNext("loves"); //at this point, print "Result = bart loves doughnut". 
                     //The last value of o1 is "bart",
                     //and the last value of o3 is "doughnut"
Thread.sleep(1000);
o1?.onNext("marge"); //marge loves doughnut
Thread.sleep(1000);
o2?.onNext("hates"); //marge hates doughnut
Thread.sleep(1000);
o3?.onNext("pie");   //marge hates pie
Thread.sleep(1000);
o3?.onNext("cake");  //marge hates cake
Thread.sleep(1000);
o2?.onNext("sees");  //marge sees cake
Thread.sleep(1000);

Log.d("so", "Done");
```

But the actual result was

```
Result = homer loves doughnut
Result = bart hates pie
Result = marge sees cake
Done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that `zip` ([docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)) only uses elements once. If you merge streams [A1] and [B1,B2,B3] it will only produce [(A1,B2)] and then wait for the next A, even though the next B's are already available.

However, the operator `combineLatest` ([docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)) can achieve the desired behavior:

```
Observable.combineLatest(o1, o2, o3, Function3<String, String, String, String> {
    t1, t2, t3 -> arrayOf(t1, t2, t3).joinToString(" ")
}).subscribe {
    println(it)
}
```

Output:

```
bart loves doughnut
marge loves doughnut
marge hates doughnut
marge hates pie
marge hates cake
marge sees cake
Done
```

As a general recommendation: check out *all* the [available operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) in ReactiveX. The graphical documentation is very intuitive. In the end, these are the basic building blocks you want to *fully* understand to realize more complex behavior.

Comment: It works as I expected. Thank you for the operator list page, too.